# Majuscules dans les grades et titres millitaires

Tags: correspondance, majuscules

Dans une correspondance à un militaire, doit-on mettre une majuscule à son titre militaire comme on le fait pour *Monsieur* et *Madame* ? Doit-on écrire à un général « Général Dupond » ?

Si oui, y’a-t-il un rapport hiérarchique à prendre en compte ? Si un lieutenant s’adresse à un général lui écrit-il « […] Général Dupond » quand ce dernier lui donne du « […] lieutenant Tartempion » sans majuscule ?

Comment: Ces deux références [Majuscules aux grades militaires](https://www.ramillon-thilliez.net/post/%C3%A0-vos-ordres-mon-capitaine) (français) et [Termium Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_g&page=9gPqpCEZ5cFc.html) (Québec) disent la même chose. Ainsi que la [BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3628).

Comment: @None Pourquoi ne pas écrire une réponse basée sur ces sources ? :)

Comment: Oui, carrément. Je pourrais alors la marquer comme solution.

Comment: Peut-être à cause des questions qui ne sont pas bien recherchées.  Comme ces références répondent sans problème à la question, la réponse est bien *dico*.

Comment: Libre aussi à vous de répondre vous-même à votre question, en vous basant sur les source citées par @None :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quand on écrit un courrier, on utilise un entête standard qui comporte toujours une majuscule pour le grade ou la fonction (mais pas pour l'article). Enfin le titre de civilité (*monsieur*, *madame*) s'écrit aussi avec une majuscule car on s'adresse directement aux personnes:

- Monsieur le Général
- Madame la Députée
- Madame la Présidente
- Monsieur le Responsable des achats.

L'ordre hiérarchique éventuel n'est pas pris en compte dans l'entête.

---

Mais attention, cet usage des majuscules est propre aux courriers.

En français, on constate fréquemment l'abus de majuscules dans les récits, et encore plus dans les requêtes, exemple: *... inaugurée par Monsieur le Président de La République Française....*, un passage avec quatre majuscules injustifiées sur les cinq! En réalité les grades et les fonctions sont des noms communs et, par conséquent, dans un écrit courant ils ne prennent pas la majuscule:

- La ministre de l’Éducation nationale remercia *le président de la République française* avec un mot reconnaissant pour *monsieur* Viguier et *le général Desmarais*.

Ici on met plutôt la majuscule aux *noms* dans *Education nationale* et *République française*, des institutions assimilées à des personnes morales.

Référence: [Règles de l'écriture typographique du français](https://www.adverbum.fr/atelier-perrousseaux/yves-perrousseaux/regles-de-l-ecriture-typographique-du-francais-nouvelle-edition_m915m19bqjd8.html) (les autres références pour ce genre de règles sont le [Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale) et le [Ramat](https://www.ramat.ca/) québécois).